# Deploy Umbraco 7 to Azure from VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, azure, umbraco

When I create a new asp.net empty web application project in VS 2013, install Umbraco 7.0.3 w/PM and  configure it to use an Azure database, it skips the 'create user' section but it works fine.

In VS, I publish it to a new Azure website and tell it to use the existing db server, validate tne  connction, in settings there's no file publish options checked, verify the DSN, check to use this connection  string and update the database, it says it completes successfully but when it opens the site in a browser, I  get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.BeginRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +16
Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.<Init>b__8(Object sender, EventArgs e) +253
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I've been banging away at this for a couple days, anyone got a pointer?  I'm just an implementer kinda guy  so pretty clueless about the errors.

I also tried doing it via WebMatrix local install and publish to Azure with the same results.

In the past, with Umbraco 4.x, I've just installed locally and then with WebMatrix on the host and it's  worked.

I went through a tut on installing v.6.x on Azure but that was with cloud services and it seems, from darren  ferguson's video on Azure that websites are the way to go now.  This isn't for a huge site so it seemed like  an Azure website would be fine.  If v.7 was in the app gallery, I'd be clam happy.

Help?

Thanksmuch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to deploy the global.asax file.

Comment: You are correct, sir.  I added it to the project and now it works.  Thanks very much.  I'll have to go learn why that isn't included already.  In the interim, I was able to get a WebMatrix published version to work and it did include global.asax.

Comment: I think it's an oversight in our NuGet package, I've created a "note to self" about this to check it out before we release a new version.

Comment: Same problem here on version 7.0.4. Glad I found this post.

Comment: i have been struggling with this as well (7.0.4). Adding global.asax fixed it for me.Also glad to have found this post...